# How to handle this formatted Numbers "XYe+02"

Tags: java, double, number-formatting, exponent

I parse an xml-document with dom, which includes tags like this:

```
<edge cost="2.811138559374119e+02">0</edge>
```

Now I saved the Number as a String. How can I save it as a double, so that I can use the number for further calculations? How does this work with "e+0x" ?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Double.parseDouble()`.

Live example: http://ideone.com/1NMDtL.

FYI, this is a form of [*scientific notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Answer (score 0):

This is scientific notation, it means 2.811138559374119 × 10<sup>+02</sup> (the *A*`e`*B* means *A* × 10<sup>*B*</sup>).

Use [`Double.parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) :

```
String str = "2.811138559374119e+02";
double val = Double.parseDouble(str);
// val is 281.1138559374119 double
```